# Stored procedure in mvc using EF(Database first)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, model-view-controller

I have a MVC application that requires a call to a stored procedure in the database. The function basically allows the user to select a store and enter the number of cards they want generated for that store. My code works in that it inserts and generates these cards BUT it keeps breaking with this error: "The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'GiftworxModel.Card'. A member of the type, 'CardID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name." Controller method also doesn't redirect to Index after card is created.

Context class:

```
 public virtual ObjectResult<Card> CreateCards(Nullable<int> numberOfCards, Nullable<int> customerID, MergeOption mergeOption)
    {
        var numberOfCardsParameter = numberOfCards.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("NumberOfCards", numberOfCards) :
            new ObjectParameter("NumberOfCards", typeof(int));

        var customerIDParameter = customerID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("CustomerID", customerID) :
            new ObjectParameter("CustomerID", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Card>("CreateCards", mergeOption, numberOfCardsParameter, customerIDParameter);//This is where the code breaks
    }
```

Controller Method:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "CustomerCompanyName");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Cards/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Card card, int? numberOfCards, int?customerId)
    {

            var cards = db.CreateCards(numberOfCards, customerId).ToList();



        ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "CustomerCompanyName", card.CustomerID);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Cards");
    }
```

View:

```html
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Cards", FormMethod.Post))
                            {
                                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <form role="form">
                                                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CardID)
                                               
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Store</label>
                                                    @Html.DropDownList("CustomerID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    Number of Cards: <input type="text" name="numberOfCards"/>
                                                </div>
                                                 <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: #0a9dbd; color: white;" />
                                                }
```

Stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @NumberOfRows as integer = 0;

DECLARE @LoopNumber as integer = 0
WHILE @LoopNumber < @NumberOfCards
Begin

INSERT INTO Cards
(
    CustomerID,
    CardDate
)
VALUES
(
    @CustomerID,
    GetDate()
)


SET @LoopNumber = @LoopNumber + 1
END
SELECT        Customers.CustomerCompanyName, Cards.CardNumber
FROM            Customers INNER JOIN
                         Cards ON Customers.CustomerID = Cards.CustomerID
                    WHERE Customers.CustomerID = @CustomerID
                    ORDER BY CardID ASC


OFFSET @NumberOfRows ROWS

FETCH NEXT @NumberOfCards ROWS ONLY
END
```

Comment: The stored procedure will need to return all of the properties that are in the `cards` model

Comment: Try changing SELECT statement to this: `SELECT        Customers.CustomerCompanyName, Cards.CardID, Cards.CardNumber FROM Customers INNER JOIN Cards ...`. Certainly this error comes from non-existent column in `ExecuteFunction` query result mapping.

Comment: Thank you. This solved all my issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error you are getting:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified GiftworxModel.Card. A member of the type, CardID, does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

You have `CardID` property in `GiftworxModel.Card` class but you are not returning the `CardID` from the stored procedure. Just try passing CardID from the stored procedure. So basically your stored procedure result set should return all fields present in `GiftworxModel.Card` class.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to map your stored procedure result to a "Card" object but the mapping fails. I can't tell for sure as I can't see the select that is returned by the stored procedure but you either don't return a "Card" result or you are not returning all it's properties (ex: CardID in the error).